# Order a select result case insensitively?

Tags: sql, database, select, db2

Is it possible to order the result of select query on a db2 database case insensitively?

For example:
 I want to have all names that start with an "a" or "A" sorted together.

```
Abraham
aron
andrea
Annica
brian
Benjamin
```

Now it's like this:

```
aron
andrea
brian
Abraham
Annica
Benjamin
```

Comment: You must be using DB2 on zOS; on LUW, the upper-case names would come before the lower-case ones (the difference between EBCDIC and systems such as ISO 8859-1).

Answer (score 9):

```
order by lower(columnname);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're on DB2/400 (assuming from another post of yours) then you'd want to change the sort sequence of the job requesting that query to be SRTSEQ(*LANGIDSHR). You can also (and should) build an index w/that setting so there's an index to use.

Running the lower() function will force DB2 to evaluate the function for each row and build a huge temp table to handle it. It will work... but work poorly.